# Google Cloud Translate - Serbian Latin not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api, google-cloud-translate

I have used Google Translate APIs for translating from English to Serbian (with Latin characters).

Since few days ago, using `en` as source language and `sr-Latn` I was able to get correct translation but now it does not seem anymore.

Code snippet:

```
from google.cloud import translate

project_id = "<my project>"
parent = f"projects/{project_id}"
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

sample_text = "Hello!"
source_language_code = "en"
target_language_code = "sr-Latn"

response = client.translate_text(
    contents=[sample_text],
    source_language_code=source_language_code,
    target_language_code=target_language_code,
    parent=parent,
)

for translation in response.translations:
    print(translation.translated_text)
```

Actual output:

```
Здраво!
```

Expected output:

```
Zdravo!
```

Additional info: `sr-Latn` is a valid BCP-47 language code and worked since few days ago.

Thanks for you help

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have removed the feature. You can do post translate transliteration from CYR to LAT.

A sample

https://github.com/kukicmilorad/cyrlat

Answer (score 0):

It appears that translation to the Serbian Latin Alphabet is not officially supported by the Cloud Translate API, as discussed in this [recent issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248254995). Therefore it’s not assured that any possible workaround will be functional or reliable. You can see the list of supported language codes for translation [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages).

You/We can, however, submit a Feature Request to the public Google issue tracker for [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#:%7E:text=Create%20new%20Cloud%20Translation%20issue). The higher the number of us users who bring attention to this request, the more likely it is for it to be eventually built into the API.